# Laravel Request validation: validate another field based on the "name"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-request

I have a multiple fields binded to "x-editable" plugin that sends the changed data and like all of the data, I want to validate them.

But the problem here is that it always sends just 2 fields: `name=is_on_probation&value=1`. Here, the `name` key is the field that must be validated (it is the same as DB column) and a `value` is pretty self-explanatory.

I've written a validation rule like this:

```
'is_on_probation' => 'sometimes|...'
```

But then I realized that it won't be validated, because the actual subject of validation is in the `value` field.

So, the question here is: how can I validate the `value` field and apply the corresponding rule, accordingly to the `name` value?

I created this logic in order not to pollute the controller with additional arrays and logic, so it is going to save only the passed parameter.

Kinds regards!

P.S. I've searched for the StackOverflow, but did not find the question that describes my problem the best. May be I am wrong and did not see it.

### **Update**

After thinking a bit, I cam up with the solution to use `switch` and pass the request field there, like this:

```
switch($this->request->get('name')) {
  case "email":
    $rules = [
      'value' => 'sometimes|required|unique:users,email|email:rfc',
    ];
    break;

  case "phone":
    $rules = [
      'value' => 'sometimes|required|min:8|max:13|regex:/^(\+371)?\s?[0-9]{8}$/'
    ];
    break;
}

$rules[] = [
  'pk' => 'required|exists:users,id'
];
```

The question is still in place, however - is it the best solution and a good practice to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Try to merge your data into the request before starting validation.

```
$request->merge([$request->input('name') => $request->merge([$request->input('value')]);
```

Then your validation

```
'email' => 'sometimes|...','phone' => 'sometimes|...',
```

Comment: Is it possible to do from the Request class?

Comment: Yes it's possible , check this in docs
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#preparing-input-for-validation
@MaxKrizh